# possible events in a midi file

Tags: parsing, midi

I am writing a parser for midi files. [This](http://www.midi.org/techspecs/midimessages.php) table lists all possible midi messages, however [this](http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/midifiles.html) link describing midi files does not talk about some of the messages, for example, "Song Position Pointer", "Start, "Stop", and others are absent.
I am aware that receiving MIDI data from a device is different from reading a MIDI file. Does this mean midi file won't contain all of the events described in the midi table(1st link)? Does the second link describe everything that may be contained in a valid midi file?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems pretty clear that 'start' and 'stop' aren't going to appear in a midi file. They are just for the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System common and real-time messages (F1..FF) cannot appear as events in MIDI files.
However, they could be wrapped into an F7 event.